# Deploying applications built in Visual Studio 2010 on older windows platforms

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, shared-libraries

I am trying to deploy an application built in Visual Studio 2010 on older Windows platforms. However, the application is complaining about library files such as MSVR100.dll and MSVCP100.dll. I know I can just install these files using vcredist_x86.exe but that is not possible on a large scale.

I am trying to find these files and package them together with my application but am having quite some trouble in trying to locate these files.

Does someone know where these files are installed?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out [this post](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/09/16/avoiding-the-msvcr100-dll-or-msvcr100d-dll/)

Comment: You'll find them in c:\windows\system32 on your dev machine.  syswow64 if you are using a 64-bit version of Windows.  Note the spelling, it is msvcr100.dll

Answer (score 1):

You should use the merge modules provided by Microsoft to include the runtime libraries in your installer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx

Comment: Hi Adrian, what is I don't have/want an installer by just the raw .exe? Is there a way for me to just include those DLLs in the executable folder?